# Overpass query to merge parallel railway lines into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, node-modules, openstreetmap

I'm new to this thing and I have searched everywhere about this but unable to merge parallel railway lines/railroads into one in the map [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgamz.png)

I have tried this query so far but it is showing all the tracks individually.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I've already tried to do this. I have posted an image but I have no idea how to write tracks tag with railway tag. I have tried many combinations and none of them give results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.